# Listview items based on datatypes with delete buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have something like a regex search pattern and this pattern consists of objects of type `Variable` or `Literal`. I need to show those objects one after another in line like this:

[image: Vizualization of desired result]

`Variable` is blue, `Literal` is red. I have defined two `DataTemplate`s to set the colors.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Literal}">
   <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Padding="5" Margin="0 0 1 0"
           Background="Black">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Variable}">
   <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue" Padding="5" Margin="0 0 1 0"
           Background="Black">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

My idea was to put a collection of these objects into a `ListView` and add delete buttons somehow so I can delete objects from the collection, but I am not sure how do that.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RegExList}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

`RegExList` is where those objects are.

Comment: Add a `Button` the `DataTemplates`? Do you know about commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add commands to the view model that contains the `RegExList` to delete items.

There are different implementations of `ICommand`. If you do not have a concrete command type, you could take it e.g. from [here](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-relaycommand-icommand-to-handle-events-in-wpf-and-mvvm/). The `RelayCommand` takes a method to execute and a method that returns whether the command can be executed with the given parameter. If you are new to commands, you can have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand).

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ICommand DeleteVariable { get; }
   public ICommand DeleteLiteral { get; }

   // ...your RegExList collection, other properties.

   public MyViewModel()
   {
      DeleteVariable = new RelayCommand<Variable>(ExecuteDeleteVariable, CanExecuteDeleteVariable);
      DeleteLiteral = new RelayCommand<Literal>(ExecuteDeleteLiteral, CanExecuteDeleteLiteral);
   }

   private void CanExecuteDeleteVariable(Variable variable)
   {
      // Optionally add conditions on when deletion is allowed
      return true;
   }

   private void ExecuteDeleteVariable(Variable variable)
   {
      RegExList.Remove(variable);
   }

   private void CanExecuteDeleteLiteral(Literal literal)
   {
      // Optionally add conditions on when deletion is allowed
      return true;
   }

   private void ExecuteDeleteLiteral(Literal literal)
   {
      RegExList.Remove(literal);
   }
}
```

Bind a button in the `DataTemplate` to the corresponding command of the parent data context and bind the current item as `CommandParameter`.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Literal}">
   <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Padding="5" Margin="0 0 1 0"
                        Background="Black">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
         <Button Content="X"
                 Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteVariable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
      </StackPanel>      
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Variable}">
   <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue" Padding="5" Margin="0 0 1 0"
                        Background="Black">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
         <Button Content="X"
                 Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteLiteral, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
      </StackPanel>  
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

As a note, your `RegExList` collection should be an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1), otherwise removing items from the collection will not be reflected in your `ListView`.